# Revoke another app permission in android progmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Can we revoke (diable/enable) another app permission with our app in android programitically ?

Comment: tryna make a malware? i don't think there is any legit use of revoking other apps permissions, that would be disastrous also not possible without root access.

Comment: @user10844401 One legit use case I can think of is making a more convenient app manager. I.e. find all installed apps that use camera, show them in a single list and let user adjust permissions as needed, without having to proceed to the settings screen. But yes, this can't be implemented in a secure fashion.

Comment: Any one know about the Bouncer APP ? Basically it provides security to use of apps permission.Like when you close Facebook or any other social media app then Bouncer disable all of permission of that particular social media app.
You can also scedule the time of disable the permission of other apps.

Comment: @umerfarooq Bouncer as Greenify is based on accessibility service to open app settings and emulate taps on the screen. It requires screen on and unlocked, really bad, in addition accessibility services can't be used in this way according to Google policies.

Comment: @user10844401 It's totally possible instead but only with a particular access.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to perform this operation only for device owner apps using `DevicePolicyManager`.